# FastUtil - operation on Set fails with Long type

Tags: java, long-integer, string-parsing, fastutil

Minimum reproducible example below, with the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>it.unimi.dsi</groupId>
    <artifactId>fastutil</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.12</version>
</dependency>
```

The issue with the code below is that it works with short numerical values, and it doesn't with bigger values .

```
package net.clementlevallois.functions.mapsofscience;

import it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs.Long2ObjectOpenHashMap;
import it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects.ReferenceOpenHashSet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 *
 * @author LEVALLOIS
 */
public class JournalSimilaritiesComputer {

    static Long2ObjectOpenHashMap<ReferenceOpenHashSet<Long>> journal2AuthorsMap = new Long2ObjectOpenHashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JournalSimilaritiesComputer computer = new JournalSimilaritiesComputer();
        computer.loadDataToMap();
        System.out.println("number of entries in the map: " + journal2AuthorsMap.size());
        computer.doubleLoopingThroughJournalIds();
    }

    private void loadDataToMap() throws IOException {
        
        /*
        The goal is to:
        - load lines
        - split them on |
        - the left side is an entity, the right side is thing to measure similarity on.
        - in the examples below, we would expect 2 lines to be similar because they have the same value on the right side
        - but weirdly, the second example fails to detect the similarity. Help!
        */
        
        List<String> lines = List.of("1|0","2|0"); // DETECTION OF SIMILARITY WORKS
        lines = List.of("4210168784|3089954349","198793727|3089954349"); // DETECTION OF SIMILARITY FAILS
        
        lines.stream().forEach(line -> {
            processLine(line);
        });
    }

    private void doubleLoopingThroughJournalIds() {        
        journal2AuthorsMap.keySet().longStream().forEach(journalIdA -> {
                    ReferenceOpenHashSet<Long> authorsOfJournalA = journal2AuthorsMap.get(journalIdA);

            journal2AuthorsMap.keySet().longStream().forEach(journalIdB -> {
                if (journalIdA == journalIdB) {
                    return;
                }
                ReferenceOpenHashSet<Long> authorsOfJournalB = journal2AuthorsMap.get(journalIdB);
                Integer similarity = computeSimilarities(authorsOfJournalA, authorsOfJournalB);
                if (similarity > 0) {
                    String sim = journalIdA + "," + journalIdB + "," + similarity;
                    System.out.println("similarity detected! -> " + sim);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    private Integer computeSimilarities(ReferenceOpenHashSet<Long> authorsOfJournalA, ReferenceOpenHashSet<Long> authorsOfJournalB) {
        
        
        for (Long entry: authorsOfJournalA){
            if (authorsOfJournalB.contains(entry)){
                System.out.println("stop"); // never reached with example with long values
                System.out.println("stop"); 
            }
        }
        Set<Long> commonElements = authorsOfJournalA.parallelStream()
                .filter(authorsOfJournalB::contains)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return commonElements.size(); // is zero with example with long values, should be equal to 1!
    }

    private void processLine(String line) {
        String fields[] = line.split("\\|");
        if (fields.length < 2) {
            return;
        }
        String journalId = fields[0];
        long journalIdAsLong = Long.parseLong(journalId);
        String authorIdsAsLine = fields[1];
        String authorIds[] = authorIdsAsLine.split(",");
        ReferenceOpenHashSet<Long> setOfCurrentAuthors = new ReferenceOpenHashSet();
        ReferenceOpenHashSet<Long> setOfAuthorsForThisJournal = journal2AuthorsMap.getOrDefault(journalIdAsLong, setOfCurrentAuthors);
        for (String authorId : authorIds) {
            try {
                long authorIdLong = Long.parseLong(authorId);
                setOfAuthorsForThisJournal.add(authorIdLong);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("error with author id, not  long: " + authorId);
            }
        }
        journal2AuthorsMap.put(journalIdAsLong, setOfAuthorsForThisJournal);
    }

}
```

Comment: I downloaded it and played around with it, and the ReferenceOpenHashSet seems extremely broken. Simple things don't work, like creating a set of String, adding "Hash" to it, and then contains("Hash") returns false. Long has a cache, so Long.valueOf(long) will return the same object for small values, but create a new object for larger values. Boxing works similarly. I'd suggest using a regular HashSet or TreeSet.

Comment: More generally, I suppose you're using this FastUtil because it's supposed to be faster than the regular Java collections classes, but is it really faster and is it well tested?

Comment: FastUtil is a classic, widely adopted solution to handle very large collections with a minimal memory footprint. I didn't know it had these issues ...

Comment: My collections will contains 20 million keys so I need to consider FastUtil or a similar solution.

Comment: Does the Set need to be from FastUtil, or just the Map? Are there 20 million authors on each journal?

Comment: 200,000 keys, not 20 million, my bad. The Sets will contain 10 to a couple thousand Long values. Following your remarks, I'll consider Eclipse Collections which handles primitives too.

Comment: I looked up the source to ReferenceOpenHashSet and it looks like it uses System.identityHashCode(), which means two objects that are equal and have the same hashCode wouldn't be the same to it. I think that's what the "Reference" in its name means. The documentation doesn't make that clear, though. :(